proper method to reduce 2 inch pipe to 1.5 inch pipe
single bowl sink with garbage disposal installation (no additional drain pipes to be connected).
Assuming the disposal discharge tube is 1.5" as well as the P-trap but the waste tube at the wall is 2 inches.
What is the proper method to reduce the 2 inch to 1.5 inch for the connection?
Including a picture as the waste tube "unfinished" will require a fitting of some sort.
Also, can that "cap" be removed or do I need to cut it off?


Most plumbing pipes have adapters called reducers.  With enough you can go from a 4 inch pipe to 1/4 inch pipe.  If lucky that cap will be only on hand tight and not glued.

check the other end of that short pipe ... it may not be glued ... don't want a surprise later

Do not know plumbing codes, but might check on the drain pipe size required.  The adapter might only be allowed between the disposal and the sink drain pipe of two inch, instead of at the wall.

Cap may or may not need to be cut off.  If you can't get it off by hand, obviously it'll need to be cut.

First pick whether you want a solvent-welded or slip type trap. I'll suggest the slip type: though they're smaller, they're non-permanent so can be adjusted easily and also can be disassembled for cleaning.
For a slip type trap you'll need a "trap adapter." Examples are pictured below. Note they can be hub (slides on the outside of the drain pipe) or spigot (slides into another fitting). (all photos from homedepot.com)


If you can't find a trap adapter that directly accepts your 1.5" P-trap tube and fits the 2" in-wall pipe you'll also need a reducer or a bushing to make up the difference.


For your case where there's already a stub of pipe coming out of the wall, the spigot-type trap adapter paired with a reducer will allow you to make the connection without any additional coupler or pipe stub.
Confirm whether the material of the pipe in the wall is ABS or PVC and buy the additional fittings and solvent cement for the same type. There exists ABS-to-PVC transition cement, but pure ABS or PVC connections are superior. There's a little black spot visible on the top of your pipe; I think what you have is ABS heavily coated in spray-applied wall paint or texture.

Fernco reducer may be another option. https://www.homedepot.com/p/Fernco-2-in-x-1-1-2-in-DWV-Flexible-PVC-Coupling-P1056-215/100013986
